# Best Format For Partition

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, partitioning

Which format should I use as a storage partition between Windows 7  and Ubuntu 13.10? I've been trying to change the ownership and permissions and discovered in my research that NTFS partitions aren't fully supported by Ubuntu's permissions software. If this is the case, what format should I change it to? I understand that will require moving everything off and back on, but I need ownership.

Thanks,
Tyler

Comment: Please elaborate on what you hope to accomplish with permissions on the shared-data partition. You might be able to accomplish your goals via mount options. If not, you may need to use a Linux filesystem and an open source ext2/3/4fs driver in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you share a partition with Windows, you have no other choices than NTFS or FAT. Both do not support setting permissions like in Linux. ext3 or ext4 are not supported by Windows.

Comment: There are ports of some Linux filesystem drivers to Windows. Ext2fs and ext3fs are definitely available. I'm not sure if ext4fs is supported yet. There may be others, too, but I've not followed this topic too closely.

Comment: @RodSmith I know, but I would not choose to rely on them :)

Answer (score 1):

you may try installing ext partitions reading utilities on windows and use a pendrive with ext4. but remember that you need to install those software on every pc that you want to access your pen drive

Answer (score 0):

"NTFS partitions aren't fully supported by Ubuntu's permissions software"

No, Windows does not support Linux filesystems. It is the other way around.

If you want to share between the 2 operating systems go for ntfs. Ubuntu will mount the partitions and let you read, write to and from it out of the box.

This image is 14.04 with windows 7. No special configuration done after installing 14.04:

[image]

Comment: Okay then I guess I'm in a good position. The reason I asked this is due to the fact that my NTFS partition will not allow me to move things to the trash. I have to delete them immediately. It says that I don't have permission to change permissions on the drive because I am not the owner. This is the context of the situation. Any ideas there?